# I'm transferring my domain to Azure. I need to have the ability to use my @url.com email addresses

Tags: email, azure

I'm currently using 1&1 and they have a system for managing emails. I need to make sure I don't lose access to my business site's email addresses. What can I do?

Comment: i dont know about 1&1 but i just migrated my domains (daange.com & .com.br) to azure and its all working all right... i use godaddy...

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the process of transferring my domains as well, but this post is more about managing my email addresses through my website.

Answer (score 2):

When you have application running in Windows Azure and you want to access your application with real domain name i.e. yoururl.com you actually don't transfer your domain. Your domain stick with the same domain registrar whoever it is (in this case 1&1) however you just use DNS or CNAME setup in Windows Azure application so your domain name point to actual application running on Windows Azure.

As far as I know if you are just setting your domain name via DNS/CNAME, pointing to Windows Azure application, there is no changed to your domain and it will intact with your domain registrar and will not impact anything else.

At last, I do have a question what are you doing with Windows Azure as you don't have better understanding about how it is impacting your when you are making decision, so you may need little more info/knowledge about what and why you are using Windows Azure and how it is going to impact your current setup.

Comment: I'm a small business owner. I had originally registered with 1&1 because they had decent pricing and relative ease-of-use. I am also an IT student, but only into my first year, so I am learning the ropes, slowly but surely. The reason I had to switch to Azure is because of 1&1's lack of .NET 4.0 support. Azure has been a breeze to navigate and manage, and offers some nice tools into the usage of my site as opposed to 1&1. But, like my question introduced, I am still learning how to do some things. As of right now, I have 1&1 being redirected to Azure, and it's working well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Azure has no email system equivalent to that bundled with web hosting by many entry level providers (including, presumably, 1&1). You are either going to need to continue hosting your email with your existing host, or transfer your email domain to someone who offers pure email hosting. Another option might be to run your own mail server on a Windows Azure VM, but according to this post, this isn't yet possible due to networking restrictions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/18da4da3-ebf3-48c7-9462-12fa4317175b